# Accessing Xcode LLVM Processor Macros

Tags: ios, xcode, c-preprocessor

In the "Apple LLVM 7.0 - Preprocessing" section under the "Build Settings" tab, I've defined a Preprocessor Macros as:

```
HUBNAME=myhub
```

In my code, I'm trying to refer to the value of HUBNAME as a string:

```
SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:HUBLISTENACCESS notificationHubPath:HUBNAME];
```

But Xcode thinks 'myhub' is the name of my variable:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'myhub'

Can someone help me figure out how to access 'myhub' as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `TO_STR(arg)=#arg HUBNAME=TO_STR("myhub")`? (or just `TO_STR(myhub)` w/o quote.)

```
NSLog(@"%s", HUBNAME); // SO36947532[13085:4401425] myhub
```

From GNU:

> **[3.4 Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)**
>
> Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string
>   constant. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you
>   can use the `#` preprocessing operator instead. When a macro parameter
>   is used with a leading `#`, the preprocessor replaces it with the
>   literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant.
>   Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not
>   macro-expanded first. This is called *stringification*.

[image: Xcode]

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.  The one thing to note is that I had use "@HUBNAME" when accessing the macro from my code.

Comment: Any chance you can address a related question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988067/stringify-endpoint-for-xcode-llvm-processor-macros

Comment: I'm currently without a computer somewhere in Tokyo for a few days. I'll take a look next week if no one did.