# Stringify Endpoint for Xcode LLVM Processor Macros

Tags: xcode, c-preprocessor, stringification

In the "Apple LLVM 7.0 - Preprocessing" section under the "Build Settings" tab, I've defined a Preprocessor Macros as:

```
STR(arg)=#arg
HUBNAME=STR("myhub")
HUBLISTENACCESS=STR("Endpoint=sb://abc-xyz.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=JKLMNOP=")
```

In my code, I'm trying to refer to the value of HUBLISTENACCESS as a string:

```
SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:@HUBLISTENACCESS notificationHubPath:@HUBNAME];
```

But I'm getting errors from Xcode for the initialization of "hub":

> Expected ';' at end of declaration
>
> Unterminated function-like macro invocation
>
> Unexpected '@' in program

I suspect that the definition of HUBLISTENACCESS in the Preprocessor Macros needs to be properly escaped but I've tried a few things and can't seem to get it right.  Can somebody help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one *very obvious reason* why you were trying to do failed: you use `//` in the `HUBLISTENACCESS`. As in C, things after `//` were commented out so in the aspect of the compiler, the last line of yours is actually:

```
HUBLISTENACCESS=STR("Endpoint=sb:
```

To test it, just remove one slash and it will work again. What you were doing like trying to define things as such:

```
#define FOO //
```

which I don't think it's possible. I honestly have no idea how you can do that within the **Build Settings**, but there are other ways to do it globally via a **PCH file** (prefix header).

A simple line within the PCH will will save all those troubles:

```
#define HUBLISTENACCESS @"Endpoint=sb://abc-xyz.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=JKLMNOP="
```

Then use it as below: (no more `@` needed!)

```
NSLog(@"%@", HUBLISTENACCESS);
```

Comment: So I found a potential solution to get around the double-slash problem: Insert a "$()" between the two slashes;  For example: WEBSITE_URL = https:/$()/www.example.com.  See the accpted solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317844/how-do-i-configure-full-urls-in-xcconfig-files